# Is this possible to monitor 12500kB/s continuous data?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I failed to make a monitor program to show serial port data, the serial port baud rate is 100kbps. When I open the port, the program freeze. I make a analyze on the program, found that it take 99.9% CPU time on presentation.
First, I've found that I should open "virtualization", and make "Usercontrol" know his actual height. Still freeze when open the serial port.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CanModule.Views.CanModuleView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="{Binding ActualHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="1920">
.....
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="10">
            <ScrollViewer VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <DataGrid x:Name="MsgDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" Width="600" RowHeight="20" IsReadOnly="True" 
                          CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
                          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                               CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"></DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
......
```

Second, I make dispatcher period called for test. When open the port, only show data once, then freeze again.

```
while(true){
var num = await _port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(dataBuffer, 0, 4096);
                ....
                if (num != 0)
                {
                    ....
                    var dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
                    if(count%100==0){ // 1s
                        dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { this.Messages.Add(msg); });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this._messages.Add(msg);
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

The worse is that this is a real time monitor program, I should put the newest data on the screen,and keep the scroll to the end, so the virtualization may not suit for this program. 
What's the right way to make this program work.

Comment: What are you doing exactly? (why are you adding to messages on the dispatcher once every 100 times and adding to something else the rest of the time)? And remove the thread.sleep it has nothing to do there and could also be the cause of your issues (it's not there to help you on timing or synchronisation, it guarantees it will sleep at least that long but it can sleep a lot longer, so it could well be sleeping 1 second every time it's called or more)

Comment: Also to answer your question ahead of time (since we're missing information to answer it fully) you won't be limited by the presentation (you may have to batch however to update say once every 500ms instead of every few ms but visually this shouldn't change anything for your end user). WPF hapilly handles a lot of data and i'm having no issues with hundreds of thouthands of templated elements

Comment: @RonanThibaudau thanks, I made a mistake at Thread.Sleep.

Answer (score 2):

No, a 100kbps data stream is not a problem to the processor.  For comparison, it doesn't break a sweat over a 1Gbps network card either.  And, as you can tell, it has no trouble firing that DataReceived event and supplying the data either.

100kbps worth of data is most certainly a problem for a human.  That's about one new character ever 100 microsecond.  No human can read at that rate.  They could not even observe it, nothing but a blur on the screen.

And, as you found out, it is a problem to the UI thread of a program.  A single byte in the data stream produces a wholeheckofalot of pixels on the screen.  Tens of thousands just to get the text scrolled.  So, as expected, you see the UI thread burning 100% core, wildly trying to keep up and never getting close to catch up.  You created a *fire-hose problem*.

The basic mistake you made is that you quit too soon, not thinking clearly what you are going to do with the data you receive.  All you came up with so far was to display it to a human.  But of course that human has no use for it whatsoever.  As little use a human would have from observing the data received by a 1Gbps network card.  So what you did was pointless, this is not how you want your program to actually operate.  You've established that the serial port connection works, time to move ahead and actually use the data in a constructive way, whatever it takes.  If you *have* to log the data so you can read it back, later, at a pace set by a human, then you can write it to a file on disk.  The disk can keep up easily.

Comment: so, the problem for me is to control when to show newest data to human? but what  does the virtualization do? I was think that virtualization done this work for me. My current way. Read bytes-->compose messages-->every 1000 messages-->update screen. Freeze.

Comment: what you mean is to  change "every 1000 messages" to async? or like this, read bytes-->compose messages-->store file-->every 30ms take the newest messages from file--> add new message to binded "Messages"-->update screen, when human scroll back for history, I should read from files manually?